# Adding Progress to Action Bar Compat shows both spinner and progress indicator

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

Im trying to show a spinner to the action bar (compat). This is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);//Giving an Error if do not include it
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_doonline);
}
```

Now the trouble is when i set the visibility as true i get both a spinner and a progress bar on top of the action bar.I want only a spinner.
The code is

```
myActivity.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

I know i added two supportRequestFeatures(wont work if I do not give 'FEATURE_PROGRESS'). I also noticed that

> supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

will only work if I have

> supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

and

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
```

Do not know exactly why but this worked for me. It seems that requesting the two features FEATURE_PROGRESS and FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS create both progress indicators and join them as a while and calling setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility or setSupportProgressBarVisibility change both visibility. But using FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS is enough to configure the indeterminate progress indicator. I wonder if it is a bug. Someone could want to use both indicators and this behaviour prevent this on older android systems.